# External library load time weaving as library

Tags: maven, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a jar with a main class.
I execute it with command `java -jar my.jar`
This main jar depends on `another.jar` (e.g. `joda-time.jar`).

Now I want to intercept a method of `another.jar` and say I want to print log.
By the way, I want to use `my.jar` as usual, I mean I'll call it as always: `java -jar my.jar`.

I have found [a very nice example on github](https://github.com/medvedev1088/aspectj-load-time-weaving-example) about external library weaving.
This example, intercepts a method of joda time library.
It has an aspect for `toString()` method of joda time.
However, it uses a unit test to intercept and demonstrate.

I've compiled and packed the given example as `my_aspect.jar`.
After that, I've moved `my_aspect.jar` to the execution directory, which contains `my.jar`, `joda-time.jar`.
Finally, I've also added `aspectjrt.jar`, and `aspectjweaver.jar` to the same directory.

When I call `java -jar my.jar`, intercepiton doesn't happen.
I think I have to tell the `my_aspect.jar` something to intercept but I don't know what to say.

Below is the main class of my.jar.
It simply makes a call to intercepted method.

```
package com.github.example;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new DateTime().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `aspectjrt.jar` and `my_aspect.jar` need to be on the class path if you use compile time weaving or binary weaving.

For load-time weaving you need to use `java -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar -cp my_aspect.jar -jar my.jar`. The project you use as a template also does it like that, see [here](https://github.com/medvedev1088/aspectj-load-time-weaving-example/blob/master/pom.xml#L74).

If you don't want to use the Java agent and also don't want any AspectJ reference on the Java command line, then your only option is binary weaving for `another.jar`, creating a new version of it, and then creating an uber JAR (fat JAR), zipping up your whole application including dependencies and AspectJ runtime using a tool like One-JAR (there is also a Maven plugin for it).

Your question is lacking detail, so I cannot answer more precisely.

---

**Update:** Because you said you prefer the OneJar solution, you can [search for my related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1082681+onejar). The group ID in those posts `org.dstovall` is outdated, though. That version was out of maintenance long ago, so I switched to the `com.jolira` fork, using it e.g. like this for AspectJ-enabled applications, of course in combination with AspectJ Maven plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
  <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>one-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <onejarVersion>0.96</onejarVersion>
    <mainClass>de.scrum_master.app.FooBar</mainClass>
    <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You've already answered precisely, thank you. I've missed, actually learnt, -javaagent part. Since I don't want to modify command that I use to execute, I'm gonna prefer über jar version.

Comment: Happy to help. I updated the answer with some info about OneJar + Maven. Of course you can also create uber JARs with Maven Shade if you prefer to unpack the dependencies into your uber JAR instead of packaging them as sub-JARs.