# AspectJ does not runs without -javaagent argument

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use AspectJ in a simple java app, without using of Spring.
project is controlled by maven.

Here is the project code, you can see it also on a [GitHub](https://github.com/jiboOne/aspectj-demo)

**App.java**

```
package ge.jibo.aspectj;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.print("Message from App object...");
    }

    public void print(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**LoggerAspect.java**

```
package ge.jibo.aspectj;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Around("execution(!static * *(..))")
    public Object dontLogDuplicates(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Message from LoggerAspect object");
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**aop.xml** in a `resources\META-INF` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="ge.jibo.aspectj.LoggerAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="ge.jibo.aspectj..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ge.jibo.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>ge.jibo.aspectj.App</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

after `mvn install` `JAR` file is generated, than I'm trying to execute `JAR` using the `java -jar aspectj-demo.jar` command, but only App object is executed, LoggerAspect does not prints anything.

[image: java -jar aspectj-demo.jar]

If I pass `-javaagent` argument with `aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar` to JVM, then Aspect object is executed.
[image]

- How to avoid of passing this `-javaagent` argument on each time?
- Should I add some plugin in `pom.xml` to execute aspect directly?

Comment: Use compile-time weaving instead, if you do not like load-time weaving. You can use AspectJ Maven plugin for that. You can find plenty of examples online, among them many I have written myself here.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for reply, can you give me a link of one of the example which fits to this question?

Comment: Did you try a search here or on the web? First, you should read about the [plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/). There are usage examples in its documentation, too. As for my answers about AspectJ Maven here on SO, you can search for them like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baspectj-maven-plugin%5D+user%3A1082681+is%3Aanswer). Simpler ones containing POM examples are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25480409/1082681) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650046/1082681).

Comment: @kriegaex I tried but none of them works without passing "aspectjweaver.jar" argument  while executing.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Sorry, "tried, doesn't work" does not qualify as a debuggable problem description. I need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either in your updated question or on GitHub.

Comment: BTW, as you can clearly see in the POMs, `aspectjrt` (AspectJ runtime) is a dependency. Of course that one (size 119 K) needs to be on the classpath, but not `aspectjweaver` (1.9 M). The latter is a superset of the former and only needed for LTW. If you like it easy, package everything into an executable JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution/workaround was to add `aspectj-maven-plugin` for compile-time weaving(*in this case `aop.xml` file is not needed anymore*)

and package projects with its dependencies in to executable jar using `maven-assembly-plugin` (*there are other ways also to package executable jars with libs/dependencies*)

**pom.xml**

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ge.jibo.aspectj.App
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

execution of `mvn install` generates additional jar file `aspectj-demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

`java -jar aspectj-demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
[image]

Comment: Great that I could help you solve your problem. Because you mentioned other uber JAR solutions: One would be One-JAR, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62707083/1082681). It also contains a link to other answers in which I mentioned it. But of course Maven Assembly is also fine and probably more popular because it is actively maintained. I am just used to using One-JAR for stand-alone AspectJ apps.

Comment: Yes, you are right. your comments was very helpful to solve this issue. Thanks! One-JAR  is good, but if you rename generated JAR it wont be execute properly anymore. in case of Assembly you can change name without any problem.

Comment: What do you mean, you cannot rename the JAR? If you are talking about the uber JAR generated by One-JAR, of course you can rename it to your heart's content. The JRE does not care about the JAR name. Please be more specific about your problem. Are you trying to rename anything inside the uber JAR? If so, how and when?

Comment: you are right, you can rename it manually and it will work (Tested). problem occurs when changing name of JAR in pom.xml. if you add <filename>                  ${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename> within one-jar plugin, execution of JAR will throw "java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" exception.

Comment: I never do that, but you can. You must not use the exact same file name for both original and one-jar artifact, though, which is what you tried to do. That is a mistake. So first, you tell maven-jar-plugin to use something like `<finalName>${project.build.finalName}.orig</finalName>` (without the extension!), resulting in `my_artifact-1.2.orig.jar`. Then you add a corresponding `<mainJarFilename>${project.build.finalName}.orig.${project.packaging}</mainJarFilename>` plus `<filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename>` to the One-JAR plugin configuration and you are fine.

Comment: @Ravi, you are right, it is an old question, and it is about Maven. So please, do not hijack it, but instead search for corresponding answers for Gradle here and/or learn about the [Freefair AspectJ](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.aspectj) Gradle plugin. No more comments about this topic here, please. If after following my hints you still have problems, ask a new question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in it.

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment as it is unrelated here as pointed out by kriegaex.